# Setting function max instances limits in index.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

Are we able to specify the max instances in the index.js export declaration?

https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/max-instances

e.g. this

```
exports.myFunction = functions.region(MY_REGION).https.onCall((data, context) => {

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the magic configuration:

```
functions
    .runWith({ maxInstances: 1 })
    ...
```

See: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/pull/624